# Debuggin function translation

Tags: r, function

I tried to "translate" the `matrix` function arguments to portuguese doing this:

```
portuguese.matrix <- function(dados = NA, nlin = 1, ncol = 1, porlin = FALSE,
                              dimnomes = NULL) {
    matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow,
           dimnames)
}
```

so, I tried to have this output:

```
matrix(data = rnorm(9) ,nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f")))

            d          e         f
a  0.01874617 -0.5991677 -1.208076
b -0.18425254  0.2945451 -0.363676
c -1.37133055  0.3897943 -1.626673
```

this is what I got:

```
portuguese.matrix(dados = rnorm(9) ,nlin = 3, ncol = 3, dimnomes = list(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f")))
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
Called from: as.vector(data)
Browse[1]>
```

And R studio opens a window showing this:

[image]

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Inside the function, you showed `data` instead of `dados` and `nrow` instead of `nlin`.  The arguments of the function should match with the input arguments in `matrix`

Comment: Do you just want to rename the `matrix` function signature with your own names via a wrapper function?

Comment: try `matrix(dados, nlin, ncol, porlin, dimnomes)` inside your function. Acabé (espero :-)

Comment: Got it! it solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
portuguese.matrix <- function(dados = NA, nlin = 1, ncol = 1, porlin = FALSE, dimnomes = NULL) {
  matrix(data = dados,
         nrow = nlin,
         ncol = ncol,
         byrow = porlin,
         dimnames = dimnomes)
 }

 set.seed(123) 
 portuguese.matrix(dados = rnorm(9) ,nlin = 3, ncol = 3, dimnomes =  list(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f")))
```

You can use `set.seed(number)` when using random number functions for fixing the output.

I got this output:

```
structure(c(-0.560475646552213, -0.23017748948328, 1.55870831414912, 
0.070508391424576, 0.129287735160946, 1.71506498688328, 0.460916205989202, 
-1.26506123460653, -0.686852851893526), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f")))
```